# SilverStripe 3.5.1 - Display userforms module inside a modal window

Tags: php, forms, module, silverstripe

I'm trying to get a userform module form to display in a modal window. I do realize that userforms are pagetypes, but the reason behind this is basically to give content managers full control over the form's creation rather than do something custom.

I have managed to accomplish getting the userform into the modal by extending the `UserDefinedForm` pagetype so I have access to all the methods of `UserDefinedForm`:

```
<?php

class GatewayForm extends UserDefinedForm {

    private static $db = array(

    );
}
```

I created a `GatewayForm` pagetype in the admin, create the form fields, and set up this code in `Page.php` to get it (the form modal needs to appear on every page on the site, just FYI):

```
 public function ShowForm(){
    $get = DataObject::get_one('SiteTree', "ClassName='GatewayForm'");
    return new UserDefinedForm_Controller($get);
}
```

Then, I created an Includes file called `GatewayForm.ss` and referenced the `$ShowForm` code in there to display the form:

```
<div class="slider register-photo">
    <div class="form-inner">
        <div class="form-container gatewayform">
            <a class="sidebar">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left icon-arrow arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="closeBtn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </a>
            <h2 class="text-center black"><strong>Sample header</strong></h2>
            <p class="light">-- Free Download --</p>

            <% control $ShowForm %>
                $Form
            <% end_control %>

            <a href="privacy-policy" class="already" target="_blank"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock icon-lock"></span>We will never share your information.</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This does seem to work as the form displays in the modal. The problem now is how to prevent the page from reloading when I hit submit. It seems to be the way the userform module works as, at the end of the `process()` function in `UserDefinedForm.php`, there is a redirect:

```
 return $this->redirect($this->Link('finished') . $referrer . $this->config()->finished_anchor);
```

What I want to do is submit the form and display any validation errors and the success message inside the modal window. Currently, if I click submit, the page reloads. If there are errors, they do display in the modal with the form but after a successful submission, I'm sent to a new page with the thank you message on it.

The only thing I could think of is maybe displaying a userform inside an iframe, but I'm not to keen on using iframes if there is a better option. I could override the `process()` function found in `UserDefinedForm.php` to do something other than the redirect at the end but I'm not sure what I put in its place instead.